# Developing backend Webservice and Database for iPhone App for Standalone person

Tags: iphone, database, web-services, web-hosting

I want to develop my iPhone app but I am not sure what could be the options I have for hosting database and webservice to communicate with my iPhone App. Could someone please suggest me what could be the best way to go for this?

I know how to build everything but never come across this situation. I have been working in  environment where we ask Admin to give us Server where we host everything but if I want to do it myself and don't have server infrastructure what could be the options do I have? Do I need to purchase from web hosting provider?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, I've developed back-end part for iPad client. It was REST, ASP.NET Web API (WCF Web API) and as database on back-end MS SQL Server and MySQL.

Anyway for mobile clients you can freely use REST. It can be ASP.NET Web API from .NET or other libraries that help to make REST services for example from Java.

REST is good consumed by mobile client applications. And then from client application perspective, it's no matter what database back-end will have.

Speaking about hosting it also depends from requirements to back-end. When you have no server infrastructure, you can use cloud PaaS like Amazon AWS (EC2) for example. Or host server it by yourslef.

Comment: Hi mate, I know how to develop everything(iphone/ipad side, database, and webservice or website)...I don't have servers my own so I am just looking for what could be the best option for me to go for. Where do I host my webservice and database etc etc?

Comment: You can consider using cloud hosting when you do not have servers and do not what to prepare server infrustructure by yourself. For example Amazon AWS - Amazon EC2. With EC2 you can get a virtual server, and later configure DNS for it. When later you need more servers it's easy to create new EC2 instances. Look at http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/, also there are options with databases there. It could be Amazon RDS (actually MySQL hosted in cloud) or SimpleDb